# Python regex sub space

Tags: python, regex, whitespace

**CODE:**

```
word = 'aiuhsdjfööäö ; sdfdfd'
word1=re.sub('[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9\t\r\n\f()!{$}.+?|]',"""\[^^0-9\t\r\n\f(!){$}.+?|\]*""", word) ; print 'word=  ', word
word2=re.sub('[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9\t\r\n\f()!{$}.+?|]',"""\[^^0-9\\t\\r\\n\\f(!){$}.+?|\]*""", word) ; print 'word=  ', word
word3=re.sub('[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9\t\r\n\f()!{$}.+?|]',"""\[^^0-9\\\t\\\r\\\n\\\f(!){$}.+?|\]*""", word) ; print 'word=  ', word
word4=re.sub('[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9\s()!{$}.+?|]',"""\[^^0-9\s(!){$}.+?|\]*""", word) ; print 'word=  ', word
word5=re.sub('[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9\s()!{$}.+?|]',"""\[^^0-9\\s(!){$}.+?|\]*""", word) ; print 'word=  ', word
word6=re.sub('[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9\s()!{$}.+?|]',"""\[^^0-9\\\s(!){$}.+?|\]*""", word) ; print 'word=  ', word

F=open('suoriP.txt','w')
F.writelines(word1+'\n\n'+word2+'\n\n'+word3+'\n\n'+word4+'\n\n'+word5+'\n\n'+word6)
F.close
```

**RESULT:**

```
aiuhsdjfööäö\[^^0-9 

(!){$}.+?|\]*\[^^0-9    

(!){$}.+?|\]*\[^^0-9    

(!){$}.+?|\]*sdfdfd

aiuhsdjfööäö\[^^0-9 

(!){$}.+?|\]*\[^^0-9    

(!){$}.+?|\]*\[^^0-9    

(!){$}.+?|\]*sdfdfd

aiuhsdjfööäö\[^^0-9\    \
\
\(!){$}.+?|\]*\[^^0-9\  \
\
\(!){$}.+?|\]*\[^^0-9\  \
\
\(!){$}.+?|\]*sdfdfd

aiuhsdjfööäö \[^^0-9\s(!){$}.+?|\]* sdfdfd

aiuhsdjfööäö \[^^0-9\s(!){$}.+?|\]* sdfdfd

aiuhsdjfööäö \[^^0-9\s(!){$}.+?|\]* sdfdfd
```

**QUESTION:**

I do not understand why:

1. re does not substitute backslashes, \s, \s, \\s are all substituted as \s
2. re does not substitute \\t\\r\\n\\f for ';'

I am trying to generate complicated re patterns with variable names by analyzing a file.

I am not able to generate space characters representation `[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9\t\r\n\f()!{$}.+?|]`. I mean if I find in the text file ';' with `word1=re.sub('[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9\t\r\n\f()!{$}.+?|]',....`

I am not able to substitute this character ';' by string  '[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9\t\r\n\f()!{$}.+?|]'

This string is a pattern string, which I use in `re.search` to extract certain words as variables.

**SOLUTION**< WHICH EMERGED LATER AND IS ADDED LATER.

In the end I replaced xxxx instead of space special characters.  Later merged, split and merged string by adding '\t\n\f\v\r'.

```
strsub=smart_str('[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9xxxx()!{$}.+?|`\"£$\%&_+~#\'@><]+', encoding='utf-8', strings_only=False, errors='replace' )
word=re.sub('[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9\t\n\r\f()!{$}.+?|£$\%&_+~#\'@><]+',strsub,word)

for line in word.split('xxxx'):
     str2=str2+'\\t\\n\\f\\v\\r'+line 
     F.writelines(str2)
```

Comment: Use raw strings for regexes (`r'str'` instead of `'str'`) so backslashes won't have a special meaning (python-wise)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still it is inersting for me. The line1 is substituted instead of ';' normally, line2 with strange characters. what is the reason?  line1=\[^^äÄöÖåÅA-Za-z0-9\(\)!{$}.+?|`\"£$\%&_+~#\'@><]+      line2='\\t\\n\\f\\r\\v'

Comment: Please edit your original post to add this additional information instead of using comments.

Comment: Can you please post your answer as an answer instead of an edit to the question?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `re.sub` the second part won't be regex -- you simply should group it and call it in `\1` or `\2` for example:

```
 word="aiuhsdjfööäö"
 word1=re.sub("(.+?)[äa](.+?)","\1a\2 [corrected]",word)
```

What I did above is completely unnecessary but I did it to show my point that using `[` doesn't have to come after `\` when you use it as the second part of `re.sub`